# How to rewrite URL to friendly URL?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm working on the .htaccess file for creating SEO Friendly URLs for my site. Still experimenting with it and it not works so far.

I was looking some help to make it work good.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ ?m=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

From:

```
www.testing.com/?m=bestproduct&id=admin
```

To:

```
www.testing.com/bestproduct/admin
```

---

From:

```
www.testing.com/?m=product&id=admin
```

To:

```
www.testing.com/product/admin
```

---

From:

```
www.testing.com/?m=company&id=admin
```

To:

```
www.testing.com/company/admin
```

Anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're thinking in the wrong way. URL rewriting allow you to do this : **REWRITTEN => ORIGINAL**, and not the opposite.

Your rules a almost good, here's a correction :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ ?m=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Then, **always use rewritten URLs in your code**.